# Apple Cinema Display on USB hub

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, cinema-display

I recently buy a MacBook pro 13' M1 2020 and a USB-C to USB 3 hub to plug my old hard disk, old usb mouse and my old apple cinema display monitor (with usb, vga and firewire).

[image]

As you can see on the screenshoot, my macbook knows that monitor exists but can't detect it.

I read i have to reset SMC but i don't see how to do that with a MacBook pro 13' M1 2020.
Perhaps there is another solution to detect it.

Comment: @bklps  Apple Cinema Display with VGA?  I don't believe such a thing exists.  Can you provide a model number?  Reseting the SMC is not likely to help in this case.  The problem likely lies in the video connection.  Without knowing the model it will be difficult to diagnose.

Comment: I think it's DVI not VGA, excuse me, it's Apple Cinema Display 20" LCD WSXGA+ A1081

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model number/name of the USBC to USB3 hub?